# Unsupported class file version 52.0 despite compiling for JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm working on an Android Studio project with Retrolambda and [DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow) and everything worked fine. Then, after some editing, I suddenly got the following compile error:

[image]

I removed Retrolambda from my project and defined Java 1.7 in the Gradle file:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

But still the same error, I cannot get rid of it.

What's wrong with the file `org/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow.class`, and where can I find it? It's possible to delete it so that it gets regenerated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was the following dependency in my Gradle file:

```
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
```

After removing it, the error didn't occur anymore, and I didn't use anything of this dependency.